# selecting data which meets 3 criteria between certain dates

Tags: sql-server

[image: example data]

I need to select all data for the jobs where it was requested by the same `memberID` in the same department (dept) and on the same day since the beginning of may. Below is my attempted code however i get:

> arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

I am unsure how to solve this? maybe there is a better query to execute?

```
select jobID,
   memberID,
   dept,
   [BriefDate],
   schemeID from (
 Select jobID,
      memberID,
      dept,
      [BriefDate],
       schemeID,
        RowCnt = Count(*) over(partition by  MemberId, Dept, Convert(date, [briefdate]))
  from [SSRSReports].[dbo].[corporatejobreportdetailed]
  where [BriefDate]>20170501 ) a
 Where a.RowCnt >= 3
```

Comment: What is the type for the `BriefDate` column?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide the data types for the briefdate column? also, some sample data cannot hurt. http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: 2012-06-08 17:20:53.923 this is an example of the format of the briefdate column. I have added a picture with some example data

Comment: your error is in where , put single quotes around date

Comment: That is because you do not have your date literal as a string, you have it as an int. Your code is doing an implicit conversion to a date and adding 20170501 days to 1-1-1900 which is an invalid date. My guess is simply changing your literal to a string will solve the issue.

Comment: How would i do this? thanks

Comment: Change `where [BriefDate]>20170501` to `where [BriefDate]>'20170501'`